# Phaser 3 restarting tween with updated start values

Tags: phaser-framework

I have 4 reusable tweens that should move the target relative to its current position.

Each of them is basically the same as this example one, but for each cardinal direction:

```
goLeft = this.tweens.add({
   targets: gamePieceSprite,
   x: {value: '-=64'},
   duration: 1000,
   paused: true
});
```

Since I want to be able to use these tweens multiple times, I use the `restart()` method, which I want to play the tween from the sprite's current position, but even when I change the position of the sprite, when I call the function to restart the tween it plays from the coordinates at which it first played and not where the targeted sprite currently is.

```
var pathCounter = 0;

testPathText.on('pointerdown', function(){
    if (pathCounter % 2 == 0)
    {
      gamePieceSprite.setX(startTile.x);
      gamePieceSprite.setY(startTile.y);
    }
    else
    {
      if (levelStartRotation[level] == '1')
      {
        goLeft.restart();
      }
      else if (levelStartRotation[level] == '2')
      {
        goUp.restart();
      }
      else if (levelStartRotation[level] == '3')
      {
        goDown.restart();
      }
      else if (levelStartRotation[level] == '4')
      {
        goRight.restart();
      }
    }
    pathCounter++;
});
```

Is there any way for me to update the start point of the tween so that restarting it doesn't just start from where it started before?

Answer (score 1):

I was also frustrated trying to figure this one out (and it looks like there still isn't a solution, almost one year later). I have not found any methods or best practices to do so yet, but by digging through the tween object, I discovered you can access the properties of a tween in its `data` array. Since it's an array, if you have multiple properties, you will have to find the property by comparing it's `key` value. If you only have one, simply get `data[0]`. The property has a `start` field that you can set.

In your case, try:

```
...
if (levelStartRotation[level] == '1')
{
   goLeft.data[0].start = startTile.x;
   goLeft.restart();
}
...
```